# How do i make Time Series recoding variable in R. If price reached 'target return' 1, else 2

Tags: r

I want to create a table named 'diff_5'

/If price reached 'target return %'(ex 5%) 1, else 2/

For example, if 20170710's Close price is 5%+ bigger than 20170704's it, 20170704 diff_5 = 1 else 2

How can i make it?

Thank you.

```
library(stocks)
library(quantmod)
library(RSQLite)
library(dplyr)
library(rpart)
filename = "C:/Users/Kun/Documents/Dashin/test.db" # db connect
sqlite.driver = dbDriver("SQLite")
db = dbConnect(sqlite.driver,dbname = filename)
database = dbListTables(db)
str(database)
database
mytable = dbReadTable(db,'A005930') #stock table
#mytable$diff_Close5<- tail(mytable$Close, -1) - head(mytable$Close, -1)
x = mytable
head(x,20)



> head(x,20)
   Date Volume    Open    High     Low   Close diff_5
1  20170710 211888 2425000 2445000 2416000 2433000 NA
2  20170707 162638 2387000 2406000 2381000 2393000 NA
3  20170706 218461 2400000 2405000 2386000 2403000 NA
4  20170705 212805 2341000 2384000 2339000 2379000 NA
5  20170704 159220 2358000 2370000 2345000 2350000 2
6  20170703 136111 2375000 2389000 2356000 2361000
7  20170630 237551 2375000 2381000 2355000 2377000
8  20170629 166131 2402000 2416000 2397000 2397000
9  20170628 191450 2380000 2400000 2378000 2385000
10 20170627 192335 2411000 2420000 2395000 2415000
11 20170626 171056 2376000 2418000 2376000 2414000
12 20170623 190302 2380000 2389000 2371000 2381000
13 20170622 229116 2398000 2404000 2386000 2398000
14 20170621 199473 2387000 2406000 2374000 2374000
15 20170620 300900 2362000 2407000 2361000 2407000
16 20170619 226078 2279000 2328000 2278000 2328000
17 20170616 348069 2275000 2297000 2273000 2279000
18 20170615 193140 2284000 2296000 2259000 2284000
19 20170614 203334 2290000 2303000 2262000 2268000
20 20170613 172498 2257000 2281000 2257000 2270000
```

Comment: trying to understand ur question, do u want only an indicator for the ratio between two dates 5 days apart? if so, i think you do sth like `x$diff_5 <- c(rep(NA,5), ifelse(exp(diff(log(x$Close),lag=5)) > 1.05, 1, 2))`

Comment: Thank you for your help. Actually, I don't know well log return and simple fluctuation rate. Maybe your answer is right.

Comment: Sorry to bother you, Can I ask a one more question? If that dataframe is revered(ascending by Date), How do I adjust that code?

Comment: You can reverse the vector like this `x$diff_5 <- c(ifelse(exp(diff(log(rev(x$Close)),lag=5)) > 1.05, 1, 2),rep(NA,5))`, note that `rev` function being added here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to do that with dplyr. I added a column `pct_diff` to show the actual percent change vs. 20170710.

```
library(dplyr)
df%>%
  mutate(diff_5=ifelse((first(Close)/Close-1)>.05,1,2),
         pct_diff=first(Close)/Close-1)

      Date Volume    Open    High     Low   Close diff_5   pct_diff
1 20170710 211888 2425000 2445000 2416000 2433000      2 0.00000000
2 20170707 162638 2387000 2406000 2381000 2393000      2 0.01671542
3 20170706 218461 2400000 2405000 2386000 2403000      2 0.01248439
4 20170705 212805 2341000 2384000 2339000 2379000      2 0.02269861
5 20170704 159220 2358000 2370000 2345000 2350000      2 0.03531915
6 20170703 136111 2375000 2389000 2356000 2361000      2 0.03049555
7 20170630 237551 2375000 2381000 2355000 2377000      2 0.02355911
```

**data**

```
df <- read.table(text="   Date Volume    Open    High     Low Close
20170710 211888 2425000 2445000 2416000 2433000
20170707 162638 2387000 2406000 2381000 2393000
20170706 218461 2400000 2405000 2386000 2403000
20170705 212805 2341000 2384000 2339000 2379000
20170704 159220 2358000 2370000 2345000 2350000
20170703 136111 2375000 2389000 2356000 2361000
20170630 237551 2375000 2381000 2355000 2377000",
                 header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I saved a lot of time, thanks to you. But I am not familiar with that code, especially first(close) part because I am beginner. I am searching that function. But I don't find understandable answer. Sorry to bother you, if you are ok, please teach me code's function.

Comment: `first` is part of `dplyr`. First, install the `dplyr` package, then `library(dplyr)` to load it and then type `?first` to get the help page on this function.

Comment: Thank you. Have a nice day. :)

Comment: Oh, I ticked the question. I didn't know stack provide adopting question function until now.